# dynamically generated form in jquery does not call function on onchange

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, dynamic, onchange

Sorry to bother you but I can't figure out why the function "fileUpload()" isn't being called when the input button is clicked.

I've isolated the problem to the dynamically generated form-- the fileUpload() works when the form is already loaded on the page.

Here is the code:

```
var dID;
var pictureform;


$(document).delegate('.ddxaddpic', 'click', function(){
        dID = $(this).prev('.diffddz').find('option:selected').val();
        var n =$('this span.addhere form').length;

        if ((dID !== "") && (n == 0)) {

        pictureform = "<form id='picup"+dID+"' class='picupcl' enctype='multipart/form-data'>"
        pictureform += "<input type='file' id='inp1'  name='fileToUpload"+dID+"[]' onchange='fileUpload('picup"+dID+"','pictureupload.php','upload"+dID+"','picup"+dID+"');'/></br>"
        pictureform +="<input type='hidden' name='filenum' value='"+dID+"'/><input type='hidden' name='clinimg_id' value='"+dID+"'/></form>"
        pictureform +="<span id='upload"+dID+"'></span>";

        $(this).next('.addhere').append(pictureform);


        }

        });
```

When I click to upload files, the function never gets called. Worse, I also receive a syntax error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } " at a line that doesn't have any code.

Any tips?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: your onchange event is surrounded with simple quotes .. therefore you need to escape simple quotes inside of it or replace them with double quotes

Comment: Also, if you're using jQuery > 1.7, you should switch from .delegate() to .on()

Comment: You may have a syntax error too somewhere which leads to the _"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } "_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least a quote problem here ...

```
// replace
pictureform += "<input type='file'...
// by 
pictureform += "<input type='file' id='inp1'  name='fileToUpload"+dID+"[]' onchange=\"fileUpload('picup"+dID+"','pictureupload.php','upload"+dID+"','picup"+dID+"');\"/></br>";
```

Plus add semicolon at the end of instructions, it will keep some syntax error risks away